# Surprising optional unwrapped in if conditional

Tags: swift

Trying to wrap my head around if this is expected behavior:

While refactoring some code that had this form:

```
let opt:Int? = 9

if let unwrapped = opt {
  if unwrapped > 5 {
    println("Yes")
    // Prints Yes
  }
}
```

I wanted to eliminate the nested If statements.  Using a more compact form such as this worked as expected:

```
if (opt ?? 0) > 5 {
  println("Yes")
  // Prints Yes
}
```

Yet I was surprised that a direct comparison to the optional also seemed to unwrap the optional in the conditional:

```
if opt > 5 {
  println("Yes")
  // Prints Yes
}
```

I tested this with other types and they all had the same behavior.  Clearly from Apple's documentation, checking if an optional is equal to nil is discussed, yet, I did not expect that it would also evaluate with the wrapped value.

Did I miss something (and this is to be expected) or is this unsupported behavior of optionals?  It sure seems like a much easier way to combine conditionals with optionals.

Greg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the definitions of the [`> operator`](http://swifter.natecook.com/operator/gt/) is:

```
func ><T : _Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool
```

It seems that the compiler is using that version of the function to compare the `Int?` to the `5`. We can confirm this by using `swiftc` directly and asking it to output swift intermediate language (SIL):

```
swiftc -emit-silgen compare.swift
```

It outputs semi-readable code and, if we dig through it, we can see the function call it's using for the comparison:

```
// function_ref Swift.> infix <A : Swift._Comparable>(Swift.Optional<A>, Swift.Optional<A>) -> Swift.Bool
%17 = function_ref @_TFSsoi1gUSs11_Comparable__FTGSqQ__GSqQ___Sb : $@thin <τ_0_0 where τ_0_0 : _Comparable> (@in Optional<τ_0_0>, @in Optional<τ_0_0>) -> Bool // user: %28
```

Which shows that it is indeed using the version of the `>` operator that takes two `Optional`s.

But `5` isn't an `Optional`, so how is that working?

Well, if we look a little deeper in to the SIL code, we can see how. Apparently, Swift has the ability to do sort of the opposite of optional binding which is to inject a non-optional value in to an `Optional` one:

```
// function_ref Swift._injectValueIntoOptional <A>(A) -> Swift.Optional<A>
%25 = function_ref @_TFSs24_injectValueIntoOptionalU__FQ_GSqQ__ : $@thin <τ_0_0> (@out Optional<τ_0_0>, @in τ_0_0) -> () // user: %26
```

So it seems that what is happening is that we essentially end up doing something similar to (but not exactly like) this:

```
let opt: Int? = 9
if opt > (5 as Int?) {
    println("Yes")
}
```

***Note:** This works even if we do something like:*

```
let opt: Int? = 9
let five: Int = 5
if opt > five {
   println("Yes")
}
```

*it'll still inject `five` in to an `Optional` so that it can perform the comparison.*

Comment: It seems, `non-nil` is always greater than `nil`, and `nil` is equal to `nil` only.

Comment: Haskell has btw exactly the same with the Maybe monad: Just x is always greater than Nothing, Nothing is only equal to Nothing and Just x compared to Just y is x compared to y